# How to show a message after submitting a form (form made using plugin)

Tags: php

I want to show a message either on the same page or different page after the user submits the form. The form is implemented using the [user registration](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-registration/) plugin, using a shortcode.

I tried the following code that tries to redirect user to another page.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
     wp_redirect( get_permalink(977) . '?updated=true' );
}
```

If redirected, the code below will display a message:

```
if ( $_GET['updated'] == 'true' ) {
    echo "Redirect success";
}
```

Currently, the issue is that the first code doesn't redirect user after the user submits the form. If I change request method to 'GET', it redirects to other page before the current page loads.

Comment: how is your form implemented? Which plugin are you using? It's difficult if not impossible to answer the question without knowing basic things about the form, e.g. where is its code located? Is it a page template? Shortcode? Block? Where is the form submitting to? Is it submitting via AJAX or a standard HTTP request? etc Use the edit link under the tags to modify your question to include this information so that an answer can be written

Answer (score 0):

Using the function `wp_redirect()` may fail due to the timing of its usage and the already sent headers on your form page.

I recommend using jQuery and AJAX for handling form submissions.

This first approach allows the **response to be displayed on the same page as the form**, avoiding conflicts with the original page headers. Here's a step-by-step guide on how to do it:

Insert this into your form's template page:

```
<div id="form-container">
    <div id="message"></div>

    <form id="myForm" action="<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="my_form_submission">
        <input type="text" name="name" value="John">
        <?php wp_nonce_field('my_form_submission_nonce', 'my_form_submission_nonce_field'); ?>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>


<script>
    (function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#myForm").submit(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                // Check the nonce for security
                var formData = $(this).serialize();
                formData += "&my_form_submission_nonce=" + $("#my_form_submission_nonce_field").val();

                // Send the AJAX request
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: $(this).attr("action"),
                    data: formData,
                    success: function(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        $("#message").text(response);
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        $("#message").text("Error occurred: " + textStatus);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Then add this to your child theme's `functions.php`:

```
function my_form_submission_callback() {
    // Verify the nonce
    check_ajax_referer('my_form_submission_nonce', 'my_form_submission_nonce_field');

    // Process the form data here
    if ( ! empty($_POST['name'] ) ) {
        $name = sanitize_text_field($_POST['name']);
        echo $name . ", thank you for submitting the form!";
    } else {
        echo "Please input a name!";
    }

    wp_die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_my_form_submission', 'my_form_submission_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_form_submission', 'my_form_submission_callback');
```

And for the approach of **redirecting form submitters to an another page after a successful form submission**, just add this inside the success callback function `window.location.href = 'https://myawesomewebsite/thank-you-page';`

```
<script>
    (function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#myForm").submit(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                // Check the nonce for security
                var formData = $(this).serialize();
                formData += "&my_form_submission_nonce=" + $("#my_form_submission_nonce_field").val();

                // Send the AJAX request
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: $(this).attr("action"),
                    data: formData,
                    success: function(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        $("#message").text(response);
                        window.location.href = 'https://myawesomewebsite/thank-you-page';
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        $("#message").text("Error occurred: " + textStatus);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: The second section for functions.php is missing a opening bracket {

Comment: I just edited it again just now. Sorry about that, missed some new line spacing.